# Apache Camel: Convert JSON to a POJO using Camel methods

Tags: java, json, apache-camel

I have a REST server which sends JSON in response body. I have recently started reading about Apache Camel. I use following to send requests to my REST service.

```
from("direct:start").setHeader("token", simple("234da"))
                            .to("http://localhost:8088/foo/bar/?foo1=bar1");
```

Now the response will be a JSON, is there any way I get this JSON directly into a POJO using some method ahead of `to()` (something like this)?

```
to("http://localhost:8088/foo/bar/?foo1=bar1").toPOJO();
```

I would prefer a non Spring solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Little details from my side - although late

Create jsonFormatter and then unmarshal with class you need
`JsonDataFormat jsonDataFormat = new JsonDataFormat(JsonLibrary.Jackson);`
this can be used in marshalling

`from("direct:consume-rest")`
`.log("calling bean method...")`
`.to("http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=baba")`
`//.process(svProcessor) // any extra process if you want`
`.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Greeting.class)`
`.bean(GreetingHelper.class, "print")`
`.log("converted to bean ...")`
`.end()`
`;`

Helper class method
`public void print (@Body Greeting greeting) {`

Answer (score 0):

Apache Camel provides a component to marshal and unmarshal POJO to and from JSON.

In your case, it would be :

```
 from("direct:start").setHeader("token", simple("234da"))
 .to("http://localhost:8088/foo/bar/?foo1=bar1")
 .unmarshal().json();
```

By the way, you may need to configure your json library to do it and I suggest you take look at [the official configuration](http://camel.apache.org/json.html).